# Hide an HTML <img ...> with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, visibility

I am trying to make a simple game about sliding ice-blocks. However, I tested this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V3G9d/) and I want to "hide" the image/button on the line `alert('Game starts!');`. I tried `startButton.style = "visibility: hidden;";` but it didn't work...

I only need to resolve this problem, I know how to code the game itself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this after the alert seems to work.

`this.style.display = 'none';`

[updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V3G9d/2/)

Comment: Nice it worked, thanks :)
Is there any possibility, to write the "onclick-function" into a own .js data or do I really have to write this in a <script> tag?

Answer (score 0):

try document.getElementById("startButton").style.display="none"

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 document.getElementById("startButton").style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

[HTMLElement.style reference (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery UI, which has a "hide" method. You can then simply say
`$('.startButton').hide()`
You can even apply different effects.

However, this will set the visibility to *none*, removing the object from the DOM. If you don't care about that, it's fine, but it should be borne in mind.

Comment: Another advantage of using jQuery is that you don't have to write all the specialised code that ensures it runs in every single possible browser - jQuery does most of it for you

Answer (score 0):

```
startButton.onclick = function()
{
   startButton.style.visibility="hidden";
   /* OR
   startButton.style.display="none";
   */
   alert('Game starts!');
}
```